# Perpendicularity between random variables?

Tags: classification, binary

I am reading Bechavod et al. (2017) [1], and at page 3 there is written:

> In the example, each data point lies in $X = (X_1,X_2) = \{0, 1\}^2$
>   and has two features—$X_1 = A$ is the protected attribute, and $X_2$
>   is a non-protected attribute—and a label in $Y = {0, 1}$. Given
>   $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{1}{4})$, we define a distribution $\mathcal{D}$
>   over labelled examples as follows:
>
> $\mathbb{P}[Y = 1] = 0.5$
>
> $\mathbb{P}[A = y|Y = y] = 1 − \epsilon $
>
> $\mathbb{P}[X2 = y|Y = y] = 1 − 2\epsilon$
>
> Note that $\mathcal{D}_\epsilon$ is defined s.t. $A \,\bot\, X_2|Y$.

What does it mean, mathematically, that $A \,\bot\, X_2|Y$? Aren't those random vectors?

[1] Yahav Bechavod, Katrina Ligett, "Penalizing Unfairness in Binary Classification" ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00044))